# How to read 4d subdataset in osgeo gdal

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I'd like to plot an array with the following dimensions: [3x3x180x360]

it's a 180x360 world map with 3 different opacity layers and 3 different pressure levels. Thus, I would like to plot the map with data of 1 opacity layer at one pressure level.

**Question: How can I read a multidimensional subdataset as an array?**

`.ReadAsArray()` returns a [64800, 3, 3] array loosing all the data, thus, reshape doesnt work.

Visualizing the data with panoply looks the following way:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

granule = "CER_CldTypHist_GEO-MODIS_Edition4A_407408.202109.hdf"
hdf_file = gdal.Open(workdir_data + "/" + granule)
subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()
cld_amount_liq_md = gdal.Open(subDatasets[68][0]).ReadAsArray() # takes ~5min to read ...

# Shape of cld_amount_liq_md after ReadAsArray() is [64800, 3, 3] hence:
cld_amount_liq_md  = cld_amount_liq_md.reshape(180,360, 3, 3)

#filtering bad data:
cld_amount_liq_md[cld_amount_liq_md > 3.40E38] = np.nan
```

Here's additional info how I get the initial dimension:

```
from osgeo import gdal

granule = "CER_CldTypHist_GEO-MODIS_Edition4A_407408.202109.hdf"
hdf_file = gdal.Open(workdir_data + "/" + granule)
subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()

j=0
for i in subDatasets:
    print(j, i[1]) # i[0] contains the path to subdataset, i[1] the info as seen in the screenshot
    j+=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

As expected, ReadAsArray() does not work for multidimensional arrays.

The HDF file needs to be opened and processed the following way:

```
hdf_file = gdal.OpenEx(workdir_data + "/" + granule, gdal.OF_MULTIDIM_RASTER)
rootGroup = ds.GetRootGroup()
op = rootGroup.OpenGroup('scientific_datasets')
ds3 = op.OpenMDArray('cld_amount_liq_md')
data = ds3.ReadAsArray(buffer_datatype = gdal.ExtendedDataType.Create(gdal.GDT_Float64))
```

or in a shorter version:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx(workdir_data + "/" + granule, gdal.OF_MULTIDIM_RASTER)
rootGroup = ds.GetRootGroup()
op = rootGroup.OpenGroup(rootGroup.GetGroupNames()[0]).OpenMDArray('cld_amount_liq_md').ReadAsArray(buffer_datatype = gdal.ExtendedDataType.Create(gdal.GDT_Float64))
```